# HTML Injection into custom sanitiser

Tags: xss, vulnerability, websites

I found a curious website that shows listings. It allows you to type a description, and also allows for you to use tags like `<b>` and `<u>` for formatting.

But it doesn't let you do more interesting things like `<a>` and `<li>`.

From this, I think it's a custom HTML sanitiser, not the typical `htmlentities()`.

I was curious as to how it worked, so I tried messing around with the website to try and get it to display `<a>`'s but to no avail. Here's some of the things it tried, and what the website edits it to:

`<a href="https://www.google.com/">test</a>` ->  (it gets completely deleted)

`<b><a href="https://www.google.com/">test</a></b>` -> `<b>test</b>`

`<b a href="https://www.google.com/">test<b /a>` -> `<b a href="https://www.google.com/">test<b /a>` (no change)

`<b><a href="https://www.google.com/">test</b></a>` -> `<b></b>test`

That's the best I could think of. Is their code vulnerable to XSS? Or atleast even people injecting their own URL's and external images into their listing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by why you think `<li>` is an interesting element. Even `<a>` is only moderately interesting, really. From the perspective of XSS, links can do a little but embedded content (iframes, SVGs, etc.) and active content (scripts, etc.) and much more interesting. Hopefully you've tried those already?

Some things you should try (incomplete list):

- Script tags, with inline or external content
- SVGs (via the `<svg>` tag, not `<img>`), inline or external, containing `<script>` tags
- Iframes

  - With `javascript:` URIs.
  - With `data:` URIs, and/or `srcdoc` attributes.
- Using inline event handlers such as `onclick` (`<b onclick="alert(4)">`).
- If any allowed elements actually fire the `onload` or `onerror` event you can use that instead (a classic is `<img src="x" onerror="alert(8)">`
- Embedding illegal tags within one another in the hope that only the outer one gets removed: `<a href="foo"><script>alert(23)</script></a>`
- Interleaving illegal tags in the hope that only the uninterrupted one is removed: `<scri<a href="foo">pt>alert(23)</s</a>cript>`

In general, there are many possible attacks beyond the sorts of things you've tried. You can probably find a list online for "defeat XSS filter" or similar.

You can also try adding `<style>` elements to see if you can override defined stylesheets, and/or inline `style=` attributes on allowed elements. While this won't get you script execution per se, it does let you draw arbitrary content on the page (using images), including drawing over other elements.

Comment: I guess it is interesting in this context cause the site normally would charge their listers to be able to put in links